# MySQL query malfunctioning?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the below MySQL query, which should return the `t1.username`, `t1.website`, `in_count` (`WHERE t2.type = 'in'`), `out_count` (`WHERE t2.type = 'out'`) and `WHERE` the `t1.website` field is `NOT` `EMPTY` or `NULL`.

However its seemed to have malfunctioned (or I'm doing something wrong?), as it returns 1 result (via `mysql_num_rows()`) and when i `print_r()` (on the `mysql_fetch_assoc()`), the keys of the columns are their however all the values are empty/blank (see below).

**The `print_r()` dump:**

```
Array
(
    [username] => 
    [website] => 
    [in_count] => 
    [out_count] => 
)
```

**The MySQL query:**

```
SELECT t1.username,
       t1.website,
       SUM(IF(t2.type = 'in', 1, 0))  AS in_count,
       SUM(IF(t2.type = 'out', 1, 0)) AS out_count
FROM   users AS t1
       JOIN referrals AS t2
         ON t1.username = t2.author
WHERE  NOT Isnull(t1.website)
LIMIT  0, 10
```

Hope all is clear, let me know if you need more information, appreciate all help. :B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might need a GROUP BY clause at the end? Perhaps

```
GROUP BY t1.username, t1.website
```

That way you'll get all the in and out counts for a particular user on a particular web site.

I was under the impression that with aggregate functions like SUM the query requires a GROUP BY clause... I'm surprised the server accepted your SQL.

Comment: [By design, sadly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html); SQLite is the only other DB that supports the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The `SUM()` function is an aggregate, and there is no `GROUP` statement in your query, so it has nothing to do. You can always check the error condition of your query in PHP by outputting the contents of `mysql_error()`, which in this case will likely say that you are missing a `GROUP` statement.

Based on your query it looks like your intent is to have a one-to-many relationship between users and referrals, so you should be grouping by something like `t1.username` (or a user ID if your table has it).